# Difference between SRC and HREF

Tags: html

The `SRC` and `HREF` attributes are used to include some external entities like an image, a CSS file, a HTML file, any other web page or a JavaScript file.

Is there a clear differentiation between `SRC` and `HREF`? Where or when to use `SRC` or `HREF`?  I think they can't be used interchangeably.

I'm giving below few examples where these attributes are used:

- To refer a CSS file: `href="cssfile.css"` inside the link tag.
- To refer a JS file: `src="myscript.js"` inside the script tag.
- To refer an image file: `src="mypic.jpg"` inside an image tag.
- To refer another webpage: `href="http://www.webpage.com"` inside an anchor tag.

Comment: Thanks every one for your inputs.  So it looks like there is no clear distinction between these two.  I would like to wait for some more time to get more response.  Oded's observation looks somewhat acceptable to me.

Answer (score 254, accepted):

**NOTE:** @John-Yin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21549827/69310) is more appropriate considering the changes in the specs.

---

Yes. There is a differentiation between **src** and **href** and they can't be used interchangeably. We use **src** for *[replaced](https://web.archive.org/web/20160526203403/http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements)* elements while **href** for establishing a relationship between the referencing document and an external resource.

**href** (Hypertext Reference) attribute specifies the location of a Web resource thus defining a link or relationship  between the current element (in case of anchor `a`) or current document (in case of `link`) and the destination anchor or resource defined by this attribute. When we write:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The browser understands that this resource is a stylesheet and the <del>processing</del> parsing of the page is **not** paused (rendering might be paused since the browser needs the style rules to paint and render the page). It is **not** similar to dumping the contents of the css file inside the `style` tag. (Hence it is advisable to use `link` rather than `@import` for attaching stylesheets to your html document.)

**src** (Source) attribute just embeds the resource in the current document at the location of the element's definition. For eg. When the browser finds

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

The loading and processing of the page is paused until this the browser fetches, compiles and executes the file. It is similar to dumping the contents of the js file inside the `script` tag. Similar is the case with `img` tag. It is an empty tag and the content, that should come inside it, is defined by the `src` attribute. The browser pauses the loading until it fetches and loads the image. [so is the case with `iframe`]

This is the reason why it is advisable to load all JavaScript files at the bottom (before the `</body>` tag)

---

**update** : Refer @John-Yin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21549827/69310) for more info on how it is implemented as per HTML 5 specs.

Comment: to what extent does these tags effect speed?

Comment: @expiredninja `src` generally loads the file serially while `href` loads it in parallel. So, the perceived load time increases when resources are loaded serially.

Comment: So why does google PageSpeed talk about blocking external CSS references? https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery

Comment: @Freek Yes. External CSS references block the *rendering* and NOT *parsing* to avoid FOUC(Flash Of Unstyled Content) in most modern browsers.

Comment: @apnerve you wrote "..the parsing of the page is not paused (rendering might be paused since the browser needs the style rules to paint and render the page)." Could you explain the purpose/benefits of continuing to parse a page when you are blocking the rendering? Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain why use `href` for css and `src` for script? What will happen if we use `href` for script or other situations?

Comment: How does style get applied through an href? If it's just a relationship, how does it get into the DOM for the elements to actually look different?

Comment: Updated link for the [replaced element docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20160526203403/http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements).

Answer (score 74):

apnerve's answer was correct before HTML 5 came out, now it's a little more complicated.

For example, the `script` element, according to the *HTML 5* specification, has two global attributes which change how the `src` attribute functions: `async` and `defer`. These change how the script (embedded inline or imported from external file) should be executed.

This means there are three possible modes that can be selected using these attributes:

1. When the `async` attribute is present, then the script will be executed asynchronously, as soon as it is available.
2. When the `async` attribute is not present but the `defer` attribute is present, then the script is executed when the page has finished parsing.
3. When neither attribute is present, then the script is fetched and executed immediately, before the user agent continues parsing the page.

For details please see [HTML 5 recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/)

I just wanted to update with a new answer for whoever occasionally visits this topic. Some of the answers should be checked and archived by stackoverflow and every one of us.

Comment: There is a big difference in how  <a> uses 'href' and how <link rel="stylesheet"> does.  <link> requires the referred-to resource to be downloaded so it essentially becomes part of the page presented to the user, while <a> does NOT cause its target to be downloaded until you click the link. So I would say that <link> at least in the case of style-sheets SHOULD (if it could) use 'src'  rather than 'href'.  Or even better <style> should take a 'src'-attribute JUST LIKE <script> does.

Answer (score 21):

I think `<src>` adds some resources to the page and `<href>` is just for providing a link to a resource(without adding the resource itself to the page).

Answer (score 9):

H**REF**:  Is a **REF**erence to information for the current page *ie css info for the page style or link to another page.* Page Parsing is not stopped.

**SRC**:  Is a re**SOURCE** to be added/loaded to the page as in images or javascript. Page Parsing may stop depending on the coded attribute. That is why it's better to add script just before the ending body tag so that page rendering is not held up.

Answer (score 6):

**Simple Definition**

```
SRC : (Source). To specify the origin of (a communication); document:     

HREF : (Hypertext Reference). A reference or link to another page, document...
```

Comment: So a reference doesn't specify the origin?

Answer (score 5):

**SRC**(**S**ou**rc**e)  -- I want to load up this resource for myself.

**For example:**

```
Absolute URL with script element: <script src="http://googleapi.com/jquery/script.js"></script>   

Relative URL with img element : <img src="mypic.jpg">
```

**HREF**(**H**ypertext **REF**erence) -- I want to refer to this resource for someone else.

**For example:**

```
Absolute URL with anchor element: <a href="http://www.google.com/">Click here</a>

Relative URL with link element: <link href="mystylesheet.css" type="text/css">
```

[Courtesy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12032361/1697099)

Answer (score 3):

#### A simple definition

- SRC: If a resource can be placed inside the body tag (for image, script, iframe, frame)
- HREF: If a resource cannot be placed inside the body tag and can only be linked (for html, css)

Answer (score 2):

You should remember when to use everyone and that is it
the **href** is used with links

```
<a href="#"></a>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

the **src** is used with scripts and images

```
<img src="the_image_link" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="" />
```

the **url** is used generally in CSS to include something, for exemple to add a background image

```
selector { background-image: url('the_image_link'); }
```

Answer (score 2):

after going through the HTML 5.1 ducumentation (1 November 2016):

---

**part 4 (The elements of HTML)**

> chapter 2 (Document metadata)
>
> > section 4 (The link element) states that:
> >
> > > The destination of the link(s) is given by the `href` attribute, which must be present and must contain a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces. If the `href` attribute is absent, then the element does not define a link.

does not contain the `src` attribute ...

witch is logical because it is a link .

---

> chapter 12 (Scripting)
>
> > section 1 (The script element) states that:
> >
> > > Classic scripts may either be embedded inline or may be imported from an external file using the `src` attribute, which if specified gives the URL of the external script resource to use. If `src` is specified, it must be a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces. The contents of inline script elements, or the external script resource, must conform with the requirements of the JavaScript specification’s Script production for classic scripts.

it doesn't even mention the `href` attribute ...

this indicates that while using script tags always use the `src` attribute !!!

---

> chapter 7 (Embedded content)
>
> > section 5 (The img element)
> >
> > > The image given by the `src` and `srcset` attributes, and any previous sibling source element's `srcset` attributes if the parent is a `picture` element, is the embedded content.

also doesn't mention the `href` attribute ...

this indicates that when using `img` tags the `src` attribute should be used aswell ...

---

[Reference link to the W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/index.html#contents)

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking HTML4, its [list of attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/index/attributes.html) might help you with the subtleties.  They're not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

They are not interchangeable - each is defined on different elements, as can be seen [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/index/attributes.html).

They do indeed have similar meanings, so this is an inconsistency. I would assume mostly due to the different tags being implemented by different vendors to begin with, then subsumed into the spec as is to avoid breaking backwards compatibility.

Comment: No. They don't have similar meanings and it is not an inconsistency. The `src` tag adds resource to the page while `href` just provides a link to the resource and establishes a relationship with the document.

Answer (score 1):

They don't have similar meanings. 'src' indicates a resource the browser should fetch as part of the current page. HREF indicatea a resource to be fetched if the user requests it.

Comment: Not necessarily: `<link href="foo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Comment: @EJP is correct except that `href` indicates a resource to be fetched if the **user-agent** requests it. 

The stylesheet is **not** fetched as part of the current document.

Answer (score 1):

From W3:

> When the A element's href attribute is
>   set, the element defines a source
>   anchor for a link that may be
>   activated by the user to retrieve a
>   Web resource. The source anchor is the
>   location of the A instance and the
>   destination anchor is the Web
>   resource.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html

> This attribute specifies the location
>   of the image resource. Examples of
>   widely recognized image formats
>   include GIF, JPEG, and PNG.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html

Answer (score 0):

I agree what apnerve says on the distinction. But in case of css it looks odd. As css also gets downloaded to client by browser. It is not like anchor tag which points to any specific resource. So using href there seems odd to me. Even if its not loaded with the page still without that page cannot look complete and so its not just relationship but like resource which in turn refers to many other resource like images.

Comment: When you think that the `CSS` is a part of the `HTML` document, then you can use go ahead and use the `style` tag with `@import` rule. It might have consequences on the performance but makes proper sense in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

src is to used to add that resource to the page, whereas href is used to link to a particular resource from that page.

When you use  in your webpage, the browser sees that its a style sheet and hence continues with the page rendering as the style sheet is downloaded in parellel.

When you use  in your webpage, it tells the browser to insert the resource at the location. So now the browser has to fetch the js file and then loads it. Until the browser finishes the loading process, the page rendering process is halted. That is the reason why YUI recommends to load your JS files at the very bottom of your web page.