# Differences between 'url', 'src', and 'href'

Tags: html, css, url, href, src

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between SRC and HREF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395359/difference-between-src-and-href)

When writing html/css, it seems like these all do the exact same thing. Obviously this is not the case, and if you 'href' when your supposed to 'src' your gonna have a bad time. But my question is, is there an easy way to remember which ones do which, and when they are used?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395359/difference-between-src-and-href

Comment: IIRC, `<a>` tag (for linking) and `<link>` are `href`. Anything that looks like resource (video, image, script, except external CSS) are `src`.

Comment: Guys, this is *not an exact dup*, as the question and accepted answer of the other post do not mention CSS's `url` function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. In **CSS**, it's always **`url`**.
2. In **HTML**:

   1. It's **`href`** (short for *Hypertext REFerence*) for all kinds of **links**, including tags `a` and `link`.
   2. When it's not a link, you are setting the **source**, so it's **`src`**.

Comment: more information in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395359/difference-between-src-and-href

Answer (score 18):

**src**  -- I want to load up this resource for myself.

**href** -- I want to refer to this resource for someone else.

**url** -- A script wants to use this url as a variable.

Comment: Not necessarily a variable. A URL is just that: a URL.

Comment: url is value of src and href attribute

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple

you can use `href` for links as follows:
`<a href="http://www.google.com/">Click here</a>`
`<link href="mystylesheet.css" type="text/css">`

Now use to `src` put the links into html like this:
`<img src="mypic.jpg">`
`<script src="script.js"></script>`