# root address difference <a> href and img src

Tags: asp.net, html, image

is there any difference between determining the path for `<img src="">` and `<a href="">` ?

i am using the same type of referencing to root for both of them and they refer to different places, in this way :

```
<img src="/folder1/folder2/1.jpg" >
```

refers to parent folder of current folder and searches folder1 there !

but :

```
<a href="/folder1/folder2" >
```

refers to root and searches folder1 there !

I need the second address !

Comment: No, those both work the same way. Are you sure your image’s `src` doesn’t start with `..` or something?

Comment: yes i am as sure as possible !! i cant understand the reason of your down voting ! this my real code :

<li><a href="/Pages/pageCustomers.aspx" >something</a>
<ul id="info">
<li>
<p class="rightpaneltitle">something</p>
<img  src="/CustomersLogo/banks/1.png"/>
<img  src="/CustomersLogo/banks/2.png"/>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395359/difference-between-src-and-href please go read over other answers before posting a duplicate question on an existing topic

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To resolve the second address from the root, you need to add the runat attribute as follows:

```
<a href="~/folder1/folder2/1.jpg" runat="server">
```

Comment: Are you sure ?! i don't need to process my <a> tag in server side at all !!

Comment: You have to do this for the ASP.NET runtime to correctly resolve from the root. Try it?

Comment: yes it works, but i thought there is no need to process it in server side. anyway, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey Please refer this one

For img :

```
<img src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/images/logo.png") %>" />
```

For

```
<a href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/images/logo.png")  %>">My Img</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use

> `"~/folder1/folder2/1.jpg"`

hopefully this will work

Comment: sorry, it didn't work too ! as i think , '~' symbol works only in codes that will be used with asp.net like web.config.