# jQuery file not linked properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the HTML head:

```
<head>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" href='script.js'></script>
</head>
```

Here are the contents of the jQuery file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $block_number = prompt('How many blocks?');

    function writeBoard() {
        while ($.isNumeric($block_number) === false && $block_number < 150) {
            $block_number = prompt('How many blocks?');
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < $block_number; i++) {
            $('#board').prepend("<div class='block'></div>");
        }
    };

    writeBoard();

    $(".block").on("mouseover", function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "black");
    });

    $('#redo').on('click', function () {
        $('.block').css('background-color', 'white');
        $block_number = prompt('How many blocks?');
        writeBoard();
    });

});
```

It doesn't seem to be working when the page is loaded locally as it was on jsfiddle for some reason. Any thoughts?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zfiscr/9dutj67b/

Comment: share a fiddle with us, please.

Comment: Fiddle updated in post, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/zfiscr/9dutj67b/

Comment: In your second `<script>` you've put `href='script.js'` instead of `src='script.js'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script tag should be as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" href="script.js"></script>
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: @Zack Happens!! You know, we all go through it!! :)

Comment: you could use the comments, the answer is not necessary in this cases.

Comment: @MrBearAndBeer While I understand what you're trying to get at, this effectively happens to be the answer to the question asked!!

Comment: Does't matter, your answer is stupid and you just did to earn points , as I said before, you should use the comments to help the user as @HomoSapiens did, not create a new answer.

Comment: @MrBearAndBeer *"you should use the comments to help the user"*.. And what exact value are you trying to add with your comments, Mr?

Comment: @MrBearAndBeer My answer is perfectly valid taking into consideration the scope of the question and I will not respond to your petulance any further. Keep whining all you like!!

Answer (score 1):

Script has src , CSS has href :)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='script.js'></script>
```

is correct.

Why ? Please check [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395359/difference-between-src-and-href)