# What attributes in html get a resource?

Tags: html

in html there are various ways to link to resources such as *href* in an anchor tag eg

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

another example is *src* in an image tag eg.

```
<img src="#"/>
```

what other attributes link to a resource (i am looking for something like src)

Comment: <form action="...."> also usage of style attribute will allow to link resources

Comment: whats the practical real world question here?

Comment: From a simple google search i was able to establish that this question has in fact been asked and answered in detail before - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395359/difference-between-src-and-href