# URL change on a timer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I currently have a image moving on a timer where a new image will appear but what I am trying to implement is a `href URL` to the image so they can navigate the site.

So this is how I have set up the code.

The code for the image slider works perfectly fine which is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        //prepare Your data array with img urls
        var dataArray=new Array();        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        //prepare Your data array with img urls
        var dataArray=new Array();
        dataArray[0]="galleryevenbiggerbiggerversion.png";
        dataArray[1]="galleryevenbiggeraboutversion.png";
        dataArray[2]="galleryevenbiggereventsversion.png";
        //start with id=0 after 5 seconds
        var thisId=0;

        window.setInterval(function(){
            $('#thisImgcentral').attr('src',dataArray[thisId]);
            thisId++; //increment data array id
            if (thisId==3) thisId=0; //repeat from start
        },7800);        
    });
</script>
```

So, I have tried to use this same concept but changed the `src` to `href` hoping for it to work but this is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        //prepare Your data array with img urls
        var dataArray=new Array();
        dataArray[0]="index.php?page=Community";
        dataArray[1]="index.php?page=About";
        dataArray[2]="index.php?page=Events";
        //start with id=0 after 5 seconds
        var thisId4=0;

        window.setInterval(function(){
            $('#thisAddress').attr('href',dataArray[thisId4]);
            thisId4++; //increment data array id
            if (thisId4==3) thisId4=0; //repeat from start
        },7800);    
</script>
```

Finally, this is how I have laid out the html:

```
        <a id=thisAddress href=index.php?page=Community><img class=headerimage id=thisImgcentral src=galleryevenbiggerbiggerversion.png></img></a></p>
```

Why would this be and how would it be possible to make this work?

Comment: Not sure I follow; you want the moving images to be clickable links?

Comment: @Utkanos that is correct

Comment: you will find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395359/difference-between-src-and-href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a version for you using plain JavaScript.

**Here's the Code:**

```
<script>
var dataArray = [
  "https://s13.postimg.org/fa1p792lv/community.png",
  "https://s13.postimg.org/3wf5w1s37/about.png",
  "https://s13.postimg.org/iuxkqh75f/events.png"
];
var linkArray = [
  "index.php?page=Community",
  "index.php?page=About",
  "index.php?page=Events"
];

var thisId=0;
var image = document.getElementById("thisImgCentral");
image.src = dataArray[thisId];

image.onclick = function() {
  window.location.href = linkArray[thisId];
}

window.setInterval(function(){
  thisId = (thisId+1)%3;
  image.src = dataArray[thisId];
},1000);        
</script>
```

You can run it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/FrancisMacDougall/hpwj1ady/

Comment: Awesome works perfectly on that testing site but when I use it on my site http://www.etnl.co.uk/0indiatest it doesn't show at all

Comment: On your site you are incrementing the "thisId" variables immediately after changing the image. This will always result in the wrong value for that variable when you click on the image. Look at the way that I did it above in my code - basically do the "thisId = (thisId+1)%3" before you change the image.src.

Comment: Also, I could not find where you initialized the images themselves in the HTML - can you point me there?

Comment: sorry pal I have just reverted it back to the code you provided, I changed your image URL to http://www.etnl.co.uk/0indiatest/community.png,  http://www.etnl.co.uk/0indiatest/about.png, http://www.etnl.co.uk/0indiatest/events.png

Comment: it is strange as it works on the JSFiddle.net but does not work on my godaddy server :/

Comment: @fmacadee

<script>
var dataArray = [
  "http://www.etnl.co.uk/0indiatest/community.png",
  "http://www.etnl.co.uk/0indiatest/about.png",
  "http://www.etnl.co.uk/0indiatest/events.png"
];
var linkArray = [
  "index.php?page=Community",
  "index.php?page=About",
  "index.php?page=Events"
];

var thisId=0;
var image = document.getElementById("thisImgCentral");
image.src = dataArray[thisId];

Comment: image.onclick = function() {
  window.location.href = linkArray[thisId];
}

window.setInterval(function(){
  thisId = (thisId+1)%3;
  image.src = dataArray[thisId];
},7800);        
</script>

<p align=center><img class="headerimage" id="thisImgCentral"></img></p>

Comment: When I run your test page I get an error in the console which suggests that the image element is not being initialized properly: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null at (index):144"

Comment: so that means it is looking for a src in the <img class="headerimage" id="thisImgCentral"></img> but even if I put the src as src=community.png this still will not rotate

Comment: I been researching this a lot of them are saying "It looks like your issue with IE is related to how your trying to select the picture tag" is there another way to grab the picture instead of image.src = dataArray[thisId]; by implementing a document.getElementById("SourceNameHere").src