# Why does the href in a link tag behave like a src attribute?

Tags: html

I'm trying to document a solid explanation between the technicals of the `href` vs the `src` attribute.

So with my understanding of href vs src..

- href - will link other external resources (e.g. `<a>`, `<link>`)
- src - while source attributes will embed and load them in replaced elements (such as the `<img>`, `<iframe>`, `<script>`)

---

Example:

- An `<a href="http://static-website.com/page">` will link to the page.html in an anchor tag but will not request it automatically or load it's contents directly on the document page.
- However when using the `src` attribute in `<iframe src="http://static-website.com/page">` it will then actually request it, embed and load the content in the document page.

---

So if you use an `href` in a link tag `<link href="./css/main.css">` why does it behave as though the CSS style rules have been actually loaded or embedded into the document to style the elements like a `src` attribute?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395359/difference-between-src-and-href

Comment: No, starring at that post actually gave me this question.. He points out that `src` attributes embeds the resource while `href` attributes links the resource. So my confusion from that is our HTML documents should not be styled since the <link> tag does not use the `src` attribute.

Comment: The contents of the file isn't embedded in the document - like a script tag would be. It is loaded into memory and the style definitions are used to style the HTML. It isn't really behaving like a script.src attribute.

Comment: It's not like `src` and `href` are interchangeable really. Meaning, you can't arbitrarily decide on each element to use either `src` or `href`; it's predetermined what elements take what attribute. It then depends on what that element does with the attribute. There's no general definition of what `src` or `href` *does*, because the attribute itself doesn't *do* anything.

Comment: @deceze I know the src and href attribute are predetermined in their elements, but in my document, I'm trying to explain why the authors of HTML have decided to have 2 attribute names instead of one for connecting external resources to the document. Looking around and in the post linked, it seems apparent that src embeds and href links.

Comment: *"This document `a`nchor `h`yperlink-`ref`erences this other document…", "the `s`ou`rc`e for this `<script>` can be found at this URL…"* – I don't think you have to overthink this too much. It was just supposed to be somewhat semantic.