# css not detected or not loaded

Tags: php, html, css

I created a website using php, html, and css.

I used `<link rel="stylesheet" src="main.css">` to call **css** file to the html document, but when i using php to write/echo/print the `"<link rel="stylesheet" src="main.css">"` the css is not loaded even not detected on the consoles.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title><?php $this->actn->getAction("pageTitle"); ?></title>
        <?php 
        if(isset($preq[0]) && $preq[0] != "report" && $preq != "action") {
            switch($preq[0]) {
                default:
                    echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" src=\"".$purl."source/lib/css/main.css\"> \n";
                    echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" src=\"".$purl."source/lib/css/functional.css\"> \n";
                    echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" src=\"".$purl."source/lib/css/header.css\"> \n"; break;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        } ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <?php $this->sect->getSection(); ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[the console that doesn't show anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6WJZ.png)

note: I'm using php 7.0.13

Comment: what is $preq ? what is $purl ? its not defined in your script

Comment: Did you als check the elements in the console? I mean the generated code... this would give you at least an idea if the link tag for the css-file is embeded lr not.

Comment: Are you sure your if condition if(isset($preq[0]) && $preq[0] != "report" && $preq != "action")  is true? Just echo some value before switch case to check it

Comment: can you try write $preq[0] in if statement prev 'action' ?

Comment: $preq from explode("/", str_replace("index.php", "", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']));

Comment: i'm sure that will return into true

Comment: and purl came from str_replace("index.php", "", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at 
[Difference between SRC and HREF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395359/difference-between-src-and-href)
you need the href attribute instead of src, so change your code to:

```
   echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"".$purl."source/lib/css/main.css\"> \n";
   echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"".$purl."source/lib/css/functional.css\"> \n";
   echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"".$purl."source/lib/css/header.css\"> \n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ' instead of " for your echos it will be easier and will prevent some problems.

```
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" src="'.$purl.'source/lib/css/main.css"> \n';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" src="'.$purl.'source/lib/css/functional.css"> \n';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" src="'.$purl.'source/lib/css/header.css"> \n';
```

Comment: this might interest you, with " you can put $vars directly in it or {$this->var} objects, or {$var['elem']} arrays without having to use the ". $var ." method.  i.e.  echo "<a href='$url'>{$this->text}</a>";